# Google Action Console(Cloud function editor) How to add image to a Media/MediaObject

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant, actionbuilder

Hi i'am working with google assistant, i'am using Action Builder in the Google Action Console. And i working with google Cloud function editor provided in the Action Console to test my webhook. I would like to use a media player to read an mp3 song that i provide with an url. i followed the documentation here : https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media and i used this code :

```
  app.handle('media', (conv) => {
  conv.add('This is a media response');
  conv.add(new Media({
    mediaObjects: [
      {
        name: 'Media name',
        description: 'Media description',
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
        image: {
          large: JAZZ_IN_PARIS_IMAGE,
        }
      }
      
    ],
    mediaType: 'AUDIO',
    optionalMediaControls: ['PAUSED', 'STOPPED'],
    startOffset: '2.12345s'
  }));
});
```

Problem is that this code work when i remove the image but if i keep it i got an error :

```
Unsuccessful webhook call due to client issue: Error querying agent endpoint. State: URL_UNREACHABLE, reason: UNREACHABLE_5xx.
```

and in the webhookResponse i got :

```
"error": "JAZZ_IN_PARIS_IMAGE is not defined"
```

My question is how to send image in a MediaObject send by a webhook? Where do i have to store my image and how to add it in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code snippet, `JAZZ_IN_PARIS_IMAGE` is not defined directly but is supposed to be an [Image object](https://actions-on-google.github.io/assistant-conversation-nodejs/3.7.0/interfaces/api_schema.image.html), like `png` or `jpg`. A [MediaObject](https://actions-on-google.github.io/assistant-conversation-nodejs/3.7.0/interfaces/api_schema.mediaimage.html) can have a large image and/or an icon.

For testing purposes, you can upload a file to your Cloud Storage or just take any image from the web. But when you move forward you really should fix that image URL and provide corrected alt text.

```js
conv.add('This is a media response');
conv.add(new Media({
    mediaObjects: [
      {
        name: 'Media name',
        description: 'Media description',
        url: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/automotive-media/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3',
        image: {
          large: {
            url: 'https://serebii.net/pokearth/sprites/green/025.png',
            alt: 'This is a sprite of Pikachu!',
          },
        }
      }
      
    ],
    mediaType: 'AUDIO',
    optionalMediaControls: ['PAUSED', 'STOPPED'],
    startOffset: '2.12345s'
  }));
});
```